Expl3 commands in \NewDocumentCommand
It has been stated that commands executed by \NewDocumentCommand are intended to use expl3 commands.  For instance, using \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}.
Then, why is it that on starred argument
\IfBooleanF {#1} { \l_kvi_reset_adrs_tl }

is favoured over
\bool_if:NF #1 { \l_kvi_reset_adrs_tl }

in
\NewDocumentCommand {\ladrs} { s m }
  {
    \bool_if:NF #1 { \l_kvi_reset_adrs_tl }
    \keys_set:nn {kvi_adrs} {#2}
    \begin {flushleft} \imprint_adrs: \end {flushleft}
  }


The s argument type of \NewDocumentCommand is documented as returning the argument as \BooleanTrue (if a * is present) and \BooleanFalse (if no * is present).  \IfBooleanTF is the documented way to test for one or the other of those special tokens.
See texdoc userguide section 2.8.
So testing with lower level conditionals may work, but is relying on implementation details and not on documented behaviour.
Apart from being the documented way to test this, it does more than the expl3 test in this case, as documented in the documented source:
% \begin{macro}{\IfBooleanT, \IfBooleanF, \IfBooleanTF}
%   The logical \meta{true} and \meta{false} statements are just the
%   normal \cs{c_true_bool} and \cs{c_false_bool} so \cs{bool_if:NTF} is
%   almost enough.  However, this code-level function blows up badly
%   when passed invalid input.  We want \cs{IfBooleanTF} to accept a
%   single (non-space) token equal to \cs{c_true_bool} or
%   \cs{c_false_bool}, possibly surrounded by spaces.  If the input is
%   blank or multiple items, jump to the error and pick the false
%   branch.  If the input, ignoring spaces (we do this by omitting
%   braces in the \cs{tl_if_single_token:nF} test), is not a single
%   token then jump to the error as well.  It is then safe to compare
%   the token to the two booleans, picking the appropriate branch.  If
%   neither matches, we jump to the error as well.

%    \begin{macrocode}
\cs_new:Npn \IfBooleanTF #1
  {
    \tl_if_single:nF {#1}
      { \prg_break:n { \use:n } }
    \tl_if_single_token:nF #1
      { \prg_break:n { \use:n } }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT #1 \c_true_bool
      { \prg_break:n { \use_ii:nnn } }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT #1 \c_false_bool
      { \prg_break:n { \use_iii:nnn } }
    \prg_break:n { \use:n }
    \prg_break_point:
    {
      \msg_expandable_error:nnn { cmd } { if-boolean } {#1}
      \use_ii:nn
    }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \IfBooleanT #1#2 { \IfBooleanTF {#1} {#2} { } }
\cs_new:Npn \IfBooleanF #1 { \IfBooleanTF {#1} { } }
%    \end{macrocode}


Are there other instances where \IfBooleanTF should  be used ?

@Bulldrive s and t arguments insert \BooleanFalse and \BooleanTrue so could be tested with that although there is nothing to stop package code using the same flags in custom commands
